# Receiving a string value in in MainActivity from SecondActivity, and then counting it down

Tags: java, android, timer

In my program you set the string value for the countdown timer in the secondActivity. That value is then sent to the MainActivities textView which is then supposed to start counting down as soon as the value is fetched. Right now I have made it so you can set the value, and the value is fetched correctly, but what I don't know how to do is start Counting Down this value when It is received. I have already made a CounterClass. 
Here is my MainActivity Code...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String intentString;
    if(extras != null) {
        intentString = extras.getString("TimeValue");
        timer = new CounterClass(60000, 1000);
        timer.start();
        timeSent();

    } else {
        intentString = "Default String";
    }
    textTime= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    textTime.setText(intentString);
```

Comment: If anyone knows please respond anything helps :)

Comment: What is the value of TimeValue? An actual time? The number of minutes?

Comment: The value of timeValue is whatever is set in the SecondActivity with a numberPicker. It is Hours:Minutes

Comment: Also, you appear to be trying to update textTime in your timer but it does not appear to have been set. You have set timeText in your onCreate but no textTime as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your timer. Always [read the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

```
timer = new CounterClass(millisInFuture, countdownInterval);
timer.start();
```

**EDIT**

> **millisInFuture**      ---  The number of millis in the future from the call to start() until the countdown is done and onFinish() is called.
>
> **countDownInterval**  --- 
>   The interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks.

**EDIT 18-12-2015**

Convert your intentString to millisInFuture and send it to the CounterClass. And then format it back to HH:MM in `onTick()` method.

```
String time = "16:54";
String split[] = time.split(":");
long futureInMillis = Integer.parseInt(split[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(split[1]) * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not know what the value will be so the `timer = new CounterClass(millisInFuture, countdownInterval);` will not work

Comment: You could split the returned string at the ":" so you have an array of hours and minutes. Then add them up into milliseconds to pass to the timer. The countdownInterval you will likely want to be 1000 so that it updates every one second.

Comment: Could you show an example of this. I don't really understand what your saying.

Comment: @Leyton What is the problem you are currently having?

Comment: @Leyton In what format are you receiving your string in SecondActivity? What is the format of the time?  HH:MM or MM:SS ?

Comment: @Leyton Instead of sending "60000" in the constructor of CountDownTimer, you need to send your intentString in millis. Because that's the value of countdown.

Comment: Could you show what that code would look like I'm new to programming

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
TextView timeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
timeText.setText(intentString);
```

you need this

```
textTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
textTime.setText(intentString);
timer = new CounterClass(10000, 1000);
timer.start();
```

As you might see timeText has changed to textTime which is a class member variable and your CounterClass uses it.

Comment: Your example has the timer running for 1 second and calling onTick every 10 seconds.

Comment: This is still not counting down the value that was set. My question is how can I countdown the value that is sent to the textView no matter what Hours and minutes value it is

Comment: What value is sent to the textView? is it a number? @Leyton

Comment: Yes it is a hours number and a minutes number that is set in the second Activity

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you really want to implement your own class.

I think the best and clean way to do it is by interface.

First create a interface class. 

AddTimes.java

```
public interface AddTimes  {
      void writeTime(String time);
}
```

Now, implement your interface in your class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddTimes{
```

Use your class TextView variable "textTime"

```
   timeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText); //remove declaration TextView and use timeText instead of textTime .
```

start your class

```
new CounterClass(5000L,500L, this).start();
```

At the CounterClass, add constructor.

```
  AddTimes addTimes;
public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, AddTimes addTimes) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.addTimes = addTimes;
}
```

Replace textTime.setText(hms); to addTimes.writeTime(hms);

Finally. At your main activity. Implement AddTimes method.

```
public void writeTime(String time) {
    timeText.setText("Time - " + time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code as it is to you MainActivity.java file. 
Hope this might work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textTime;
CountDownTimer timer;
int intValue = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    String intentString = extras.getString("TimeValue"); //if this is a plain number like 20, 45, 209, 8
    intValue = Integer.valueOf(intentString);
}
textTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
timer = new CountDownTimer(intValue * 1000, 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    intValue--;
    textTime.setText("Count Down: " + intValue);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {}
}
}
timer.start();
}
```

Comment: It crashes when I send the intent to my MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the count down timer:

```
  new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
           //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textField.setText("done!");
        }

    }.start();
```